# reading two integers in one line using C#

Tags: c#, parsing, console, integer

i know how to make a console read two integers but each integer by it self like this

```
int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

if i entered two numbers, i.e (1 2), the value (1 2), cant be parse to integers
what i want is if i entered 1 2 then it will take it as two integers

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One option would be to accept a single line of input as a string and then process it.
For example:

```
//Read line, and split it by whitespace into an array of strings
string[] tokens = Console.ReadLine().Split();

//Parse element 0
int a = int.Parse(tokens[0]);

//Parse element 1
int b = int.Parse(tokens[1]);
```

One issue with this approach is that it will fail (by throwing an `IndexOutOfRangeException`/ `FormatException`) if the user does not enter the text in the expected format. If this is possible, you will have to validate the input.

For example, with regular expressions:

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();

// If the line consists of a sequence of digits, followed by whitespaces,
// followed by another sequence of digits (doesn't handle overflows)
if(new Regex(@"^\d+\s+\d+$").IsMatch(line))
{
   ...   // Valid: process input
}
else
{
   ...   // Invalid input
}
```

Alternatively:

1. Verify that the input splits into *exactly* 2 strings.
2. Use `int.TryParse` to *attempt* to parse the strings into numbers.

Answer (score 10):

You need something like (no error-checking code)

```
var ints = Console
            .ReadLine()
            .Split()
            .Select(int.Parse);
```

This reads a line, splits on whitespace and parses the split strings as integers. Of course in reality you would want to check if the entered strings are in fact valid integers (int.TryParse).

Answer (score 5):

Then you should first store it in a string and then split it using the space as token.

Answer (score 3):

Read the line into a string, split the string, and then parse the elements.  A simple version (which needs to have error checking added to it) would be:

```
string s = Console.ReadLine();
string[] values = s.Split(' ');
int a = int.Parse(values[0]);
int b = int.Parse(values[1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] values = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ');
int x = int.Parse(values[0]);
int y = int.Parse(values[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

in 1 line, thanks to LinQ and regular expression (no type-checking neeeded)

```
var numbers = from Match number in new Regex(@"\d+").Matches(Console.ReadLine())
                    select int.Parse(number.Value);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string x;
int m;
int n;

Console.WriteLine("Enter two no's seperated by space: ");

x = Console.ReadLine();
m = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[0]);
n = Convert.ToInt32(x.Split(' ')[1]);

Console.WriteLine("" + m + " " + n);
```

This Should work as per your need!

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class ConsoleInput
{
    public static IEnumerable<int> ReadInts()
    {
        return SplitInput(Console.ReadLine()).Select(int.Parse);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<string> SplitInput(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Split(input, @"\s+")
                    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int a, b;
string line = Console.ReadLine();
string[] numbers= line.Split(' ');
a = int.Parse(numbers[0]);
b = int.Parse(numbers[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string numbers= Console.ReadLine();

string[] myNumbers = numbers.Split(' ');

int[] myInts = new int[myNumbers.Length];

for (int i = 0; i<myInts.Length; i++)
{
    string myString=myNumbers[i].Trim();
    myInts[i] = int.Parse(myString);
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace SortInSubSet
{
    class Program
    {

        static int N, K;
        static Dictionary<int, int> dicElements = new Dictionary<int, int>();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            while (!ReadNK())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("***************** PLEASE RETRY*********************");
            }

            var sortedDict = from entry in dicElements orderby entry.Key/3 , entry.Value ascending select entry.Value;

            foreach (int ele in sortedDict)
            {
                Console.Write(ele.ToString() + "  ");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static bool ReadNK()
        {
            dicElements = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            Console.WriteLine("Please entere the No. of element 'N' ( Between 2 and 9999) and Subset Size 'K' Separated by space.");

            string[] NK = Console.ReadLine().Split();

            if (NK.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter N and K values correctly.");
                return false;
            }

            if (int.TryParse(NK[0], out N))
            {
                if (N < 2 || N > 9999)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Value of 'N' Should be Between 2 and 9999.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number: Value of 'N' Should be greater than 1 and lessthan 10000.");
                return false;
            }

            if (int.TryParse(NK[1], out K))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter all elements Separated by space.");
                string[] kElements = Console.ReadLine().Split();

                for (int i = 0; i < kElements.Length; i++)
                {
                    int ele;

                    if (int.TryParse(kElements[i], out ele))
                    {
                        if (ele < -99999 || ele > 99999)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Invalid Range( " + kElements[i] + "): Element value should be Between -99999 and 99999.");
                            return false;
                        }

                        dicElements.Add(i, ele);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid number( " + kElements[i] + "): Element value should be Between -99999 and 99999.");
                        return false;
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Invalid number ,Value of 'K'.");
                return false;
            }


            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a much simpler solution, use a switch statement and write a message for the user in each case, using the  Console.write() starting with a ("\n").

Here's an example of filling out an array with a for loop while taking user input. * Note: that you don't need to write a for loop for this to work*
Try this example with an integer array called arrayOfNumbers[] and a temp integer variable. Run this code in a separate console application and Watch how you can take user input on the same line!

```
           int temp=0;
           int[] arrayOfNumbers = new int[5];

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
      switch (i + 1)
                {
                    case 1:
                        Console.Write("\nEnter First number: ");
                        //notice the "\n" at the start of the string        
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Second number: ");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Third number: ");
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Fourth number: ");
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        Console.Write("\nEnter Fifth number: ");
                        break;


                    } // end of switch

                    temp = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); // convert 
                    arrayOfNumbers[i] = temp; // filling the array
                    }// end of for loop
```

The magic trick here is that you're fooling the console application, the secret is that you're taking user input on the same line you're writing your prompt message on. (message=>"Enter First Number: ")

This makes user input look like is being inserted on the same line. I admit it's a bit primitive but it does what you need without having to waste your time with complicated code for a such a simple task.