# Read 3 variables on the same line C#

Tags: c#, c

I have a question. I work on a console application and I would like Read 3 variable on the same line.

With the language C we can write this

```
int a;
string b;
int c;

scanf("%d %s %d", &a, &b, &c);
```

When I start the program I write : 1+1 on the same line and a = 1 b = "+" c = 1

How can I make the same in C# with console.readline() ?

Thank you in advance,

Nico

Comment: No such possiblity in c#. But you can find custom implementation, f.e: http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net

Comment: [reading two integers in one line using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881826/reading-two-integers-in-one-line-using-c-sharp) have look at this question, it should be what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is modified from [reading two integers in one line using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3881826/reading-two-integers-in-one-line-using-c-sharp). So you can do it several ways as described in this answer, but i would suggest like:

```
//Read line, and split it by whitespace into an array of strings
string[] scanf= Console.ReadLine().Split();

//Parse element 0
int a = int.Parse(scanf[0]);

//Parse element 1
string b = scanf[1];

//Parse element 2
int c = int.Parse(scanf[2]);
```

I would suggest following the link as there  is more ways described.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no equivalent, but you can easily create one:

```
void Scanf(out string[] values)
{
    values = Console.ReadLine().Split();
}
```

However you have to parse every argument in your calling code:

```
int a;
string b;
int c;
string[] r;

scanf(out r);
int.TryParse(r[0], out a);
b = r[1];
int.TryParse(r[2], out c);
```

If you want to verify the format of the strings and numbers also you probably need a regex:

```
var r = new Regex("(\\d+) (\\S+) (\\d+)");
var values = r.Matches(Console.ReadLine())[0];
```

Now again you need to parse:

```
int.TryParse(values.Groups[1], out a);
b = values.Groups[2];
int.TryParse(values.Groups[3], out c);
```

Remember that the first group within a regex allways contains the complete match-string, so the first capturing group has index one.